# How to add if statement logic in ASP.Net GridView Column

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView with the following column:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="agent_level" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="agent_production.aspx?agentlevel={0}" DataTextField="agent_id" HeaderText="View Agents" DataTextFormatString="View" Text="View"/>
```

I have been looking for a way to do the following: if the agent_level = 'b' (this value is from the database) then the "View" is not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***TemplateField*** for small business logic. If you want complex business logic, you want to consider using ***OnRowDataBound*** event.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Agents">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("agent_level").ToString() == "b" 
                        ? "javascript:void(0)"
                        : "agent_production.aspx?agentlevel=" + Eval("agent_id") %>'
                    runat="server"
                    ID="AgentHyperlink" Text="View" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This helps a lot. How would you advise to add a warning message when "View" is clicked? The user might think the website is not responding because of an error. For example a pop up message that would say "This agent level can't have down-line agents" Thank you.

Comment: If you have few much business logic, it is better to use ***OnRowDataBound*** which is much clearer and easy to maintain in the future. As it is different from original problem, could you create a new question and add a link here?